# Use of many names in c# r.net for one variable

Tags: c#, r.net

It's not like R where we can manipulate many operations for one variables having one name as this example.

```
DataIns=read.csv(file="C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Inscrits.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE)
DataIns=DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]
```

As you can see the variable **DataIns** was used tow times and even for other manipulations.

In C#, if  I decide to do the equivalent of the code above :

```
DataFrame testData = engine.Evaluate("DataIns<-read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Diagnostic.csv', header=TRUE, sep =';',fill = TRUE)").AsDataFrame();    
DataFrame testData= engine.Evaluate("DataIns=DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]").AsDataFrame();
```

It will say that this variable was already defined.

How can I deal with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Take away the type declaration preceding the variable name on the second line. `DataFrame testData` should be `testData`; you have already declared the data type. [Variable Declaration in C#](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/csharp/variable-dec)

Comment: **Which** variable is already defined? `testData`?

Comment: @Zachary,thanks it's work ! As you say i should just did like this _testData = engine.Evaluate("DataIns=DataIns[with(DataIns,order(Id)),]").AsDataFrame();_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to override the testData variable just write this

```
DataFrame testData = engine.Evaluate("DataIns<-read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Diagnostic.csv', header=TRUE, sep =';',fill = TRUE)").AsDataFrame();    
testData= engine.Evaluate("DataIns=DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]").AsDataFrame();
```

When you want both variables rename the second variable

```
DataFrame testData = engine.Evaluate("DataIns<-read.table('C:/Users/isalah/Desktop/Fichiers_CRM/Fichier_csv/Diagnostic.csv', header=TRUE, sep =';',fill = TRUE)").AsDataFrame();    
DataFrame testDataNew= engine.Evaluate("DataIns=DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]").AsDataFrame();
```

Comment: it gives me error then when i execute the program. It stopped in this line  _DataIns = engine.Evaluate("DataIns[with(DataIns, order(Id)),]").AsDataFrame();_ showing as an error : _'Error in order(Id) : object 'Id' not found_! what I should I do??

Comment: That seems like an error thrown from your engine object. To receive help therefor, you have to show more code